# Classic asp code using more resources

Tags: asp-classic

I am using classic asp for a web application. I am running the web application on internet explorer.

I had developed few reports related to sales data. All the sales report are linked to Sales Dashboard. Every report has some selection criteria like customer selection date period selection product group selection and other few. 
Now the problem which I am facing.

I open a total sales report for the entire year which takes almost 15 minutes to load on screen. while the report is executing if I try to open any other from the sales dashboard the page with selection criteria will appear after the first report is completely executed. If I copy the link location for the second report and open it in new window of internet explorer it will open normally.

I am not able to trace the problem did anyone had face the same problem.

Comment: IIS/ASP only allows one concurrent request per session. This is why the second request does not happen until after the first one completes. If you open a new browser instance or a different browser then this is treated as a different session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I agree with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405863/classic-asp-code-using-more-resources#comment81768274_47405863) posted under the question:

> IIS/ASP only allows one concurrent request per session. This is why the second request does not happen until after the first one completes. If you open a new browser instance or a different browser then this is treated as a different session.

Second, if all that is being asked here is whether other people have similar issues or not, then the answer is yes, due to what johna said in the comment.

If you're looking for a way to get around that for yourself, the way described in the comment (open a new browser instance or a different browser) will work.

*However*, if you're after a way to bypass the 15 minute wait time entirely, give some though to preparing the data before the report is called. What I mean by that is either schedule the report to run after close of business each day and store the relevant HTML or data separately, and/or provide a button to prepare the report based on current data which can be run whenever the user wants.

Comment: Thanks Mark. and Johna